# I am facing a crash related to custom audio driver provided by tokbox

Tags: ios, swift, tokbox

I am using custom audio driver of tokbox. i have a class named 'DefaultAudioDevice' in this i am facing many crashes but these crashes occur some time. Like

```
 func disposeAudioUnit(audioUnit: inout AudioUnit?) {
        if let unit = audioUnit {
            AudioUnitUninitialize(unit)
            AudioComponentInstanceDispose(unit)
        }
            audioUnit = nil
    }
```

when i set audioUnit to nil some time app crashes some time it runs perfectly.

And when i call this function then some time app crashes some time it runs perfectly.

```
AudioOutputUnitStop(unit)
```

Any soluton will be very helpfull.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a crash log? That may help narrowing down your problem.

Comment: I have similar issue, mostly when session is session is disconnected.

Comment: @Lutz this is my crash log for audioUnit = nil 

https://pastebin.com/3BYjMxdE

and this is for AudioOutputUnitStop(unit)

https://pastebin.com/Y9anGPHM

Comment: @SujithChandran my crashes also appear in session disconnect. When you found any solution share it here.